# Export all network traffic on a webpage

Tags: javascript, shell, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I'm looking for a tool that would list all the network information that a html dom (javascript etc as well) page loads. Exeactly what chrome shows on the developer tools/Network tab.

I've tried the Chromium-browser under ubutu to export this data but was not able to get the networking stats.

So what I would need is to parse a request preferably thru the command line (ubuntu/debian) which would return the networking stats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is network monitor at Firefox dev tools. Take a look at [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) where this feature is explained. It is possible to export HAR information from the Network panel by right-clicking and selecting "Save all as HAR". HAR is a network request archive format used by many performance and request analysis tools.

You can also use firebug addon which has also his own [network monitor](https://getfirebug.com/network) and extract data by using the [netexport](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#NetExport) firebug extension.

For automated process (that will open the browser, then firebug, then the page and then will export data), you probably need the auto-tool used for testing firefox which is called [mozmill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozmill)